# Prevent closing ResultSet on transaction commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I must preserve a ResultSet which was opened within a @Transactional Controller, to be consumed within a MessageConverter. To that end I have configured the following:

1. MVC Interceptor:

   ```
   <mvc:interceptors>
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
   </mvc:interceptors>
   ```
2. on the SessionFactory bean:

   ```
   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</prop>
         ....
       </props>
     </property>
   </bean>
   ```
3. within the Controller method:

   ```
   session.doWork((con) -> { con.setHoldability(HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT); });
   ```

Yet the `PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.` persists. This is a relevant snippet in the log when the transaction commits upon controller method return:

```
TRACE o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering result set [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet@5a63c2aa] 
DEBUG o.h.e.t.s.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing 
TRACE o.h.internal.SessionImpl - Automatically flushing session 
TRACE o.h.internal.SessionImpl - before transaction completion 
DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection 
DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit 
TRACE o.h.e.t.i.TransactionCoordinatorImpl - after transaction completion 
TRACE o.h.internal.SessionImpl - after transaction completion 
TRACE o.h.internal.SessionImpl - Setting flush mode to: MANUAL 
DEBUG o.h.internal.SessionImpl - Disconnecting session 
TRACE o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Releasing JDBC container resources [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@97bfa5f] 
TRACE o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Closing result set [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet@5a63c2aa] 
TRACE o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Closing prepared statement [select...] 
DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection 
DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection 
DEBUG o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - could not advance using next() [n/a] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
```

Is there something more I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: Is the resource actually mapped inside the OSIV filter?  Everything else looks right.

Comment: I have `<mvc:mapping path="/resource-path"/>` within the interceptor config, but haven't shown that because with no mapping it applies universally. Also, this part provably works because I get my open result set if I don't use @Transactional.

Answer (score 2):

By default Spring will manage the Hibernate session on its own. One of the consequences, as documented in the `HibernateTransactionManager` Javadoc, is that Spring will explicitly call `session.disconnect()`, which will invalidate your `connection.release_mode=on_close` setting. To change this behavior to Hibernate-managed sessions, be sure to set the `hibernateManagedSession` property on `HibernateTransactionManager` to `true`:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
   p:hibernateManagedSession="true" />
```

Doing it this way is bound to disturb certain mechanisms which assume the default behavior. One of them is transaction management via the `TransactionTemplate`: no Hibernate session will be automatically created. This can be fixed by explicitly binding a session to the current thread, and is best captured in a subclass of `TransactionTemplate`:

```
@Component
public class HibernateTransactionTemplate extends TransactionTemplate
{
  @Autowired private SessionFactory sf;

  @Autowired @Override public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager txm) {
    super.setTransactionManager(txm);
  }

  @Override public <T> T execute(TransactionCallback<T> action) throws TransactionException {
    final Session ses = sf.openSession();
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sf, new SessionHolder(ses));
    try { return super.execute(action); }
    finally {
      ses.close();
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sf);
    }
  }
}
```